# Java web service

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to web services and below I am sharing my understanding so far by reading on net:

Apache Axis and Apache CXF - are web services frameworks used to develop Java web services.
JAX-RS - Java API to develop Restful web services.
JAX-WS - Java API to develop SOAP web services.

Is the above correct? Or if you want to add something to it.

In my project, I am going to use web services with Spring framework.I am told that project will have both SOAP and RESTful web services.I am very much new to this.
Can somebody please guide me in this regard by sharing some valuable information or any good link which will make me understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statements are correct, but it's not clear whether you've understood one crucial fact: CXF and Axis are both *implementations* of the JAX-WS standard. CXF additionally implements JAX-RS, and there are some libraries that only implement JAX-RS, such as Jersey (Oracle's reference implementation) and RESTEasy from JBoss.

For your project, the big question is whether you will only consume those webservices, or also publish them. If you need to publish a webservice, you'll have to include the entire implementation library and learn to use it. If you only consume the services, you'll just need some generated client and data binding classes.

Another question is whether your RESTful services will talk XML or JSON (SOAP always uses XML), as you'll need a parser or binding framework for JSON (JAX-B for XML is included in recent JDKs).